# PHP general thought about database

Tags: php, database

Generally we use that database which is added without domain. For example you have domain called `example.com`  then obtusely you will use that database or Myphpadmin. But is it possible `suppose` I have  `example.com` domain and I want save any data which use fill from other website called `abcd.com`  show in `example.com`
How it would `$conn` structure?

Comment: How do you *currently* connect to a database in PHP?  When you look at that code, what do you suspect would need to change when the database is on a different host?

Comment: Sometimes you may host the same data on several domains, this isn't an issue of how the code works more an issue of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I asking general question. I have not any code issue yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite common that databases have another domain, i.e. `mysql.example.com`. This scenario can often be seen at hosting-companies.
Nevertheless it's a security-aspect to allow access only on `localhost`, then phpMyAdmin needs to be installed exactly on that server where the site is running, and when it's disabled or just not installed, then no access is possible.
So your scenario is nothing special.

Edit:
If your database is running without domain (not even `localhost`) then the connection is by socket. This is common on servers when nothing else is configured. Technically it's still a bit different, if it's configured `localhost` then a socket-connection is established, if you call the local IP-address 127.0.0.1 then a TCP-connection (like for a website).
Nevertheless, both solutions can be seen as secure while the socket-connection requires another configuration for phpmyadmin.

Comment: Not understand but.. tell me only is it possible.? To we connect other website from in other website database.php?

Comment: yes that's possible. you can run mysql on a domain different then the domains of both websites. you've to configure mysql then to listen on that third domain, or on one of the domains where you've a website. Open your my.cnf file and enable `# bind-address = 127.0.0.1` by uncommenting (removing the hash in the beginning), replace `127.0.0.1` by your domain especially for mysql. Afterwards you've to restart mysql with `service mysql restart`.

Comment: There are many videos, I propose this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BuWWzuU8uCw

Comment: What it `$con` in php of this? 

Comment: You mean `my.cnf`? this is the configuration file of mysql

Comment: In normal php we make `connection` like this when our domain and database at same place. `$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'softwebs_softweb', 'test@123', 'softwebs_cms');`But what would the connection code when we post or get other website database ro other domain..?

Comment: ahh that's what you mean!
then you jst change the server:
`$con = new mysqli('mysql.example.com', 'softwebs_softweb', 'test@123', 'softwebs_cms');`
You also can change the port, I suppose it would be the next parameter in the function, but you can look that up. Usually the port is `3306` if I don't mistake

Comment: In your code where is port. In normal php where we port!? There we only makes con file and start editing in cpanel

Comment: It's like I said, it would be the next parameter in the function, have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php. Your command with port looks then like this: `$con = new mysqli('mysql.example.com', 'softwebs_softweb', 'test@123', 'softwebs_cms','3306');`